# How do I install a printer for a user-defined type in ocamldebug?

Tags: ocaml, ocamldebug

I've written a print function for a type in my program, and can load it into ocamldebug with load_printer, but can't install it with install_printer. What am I missing?

Here's the entirety of the file printtest.ml, which is the printer:

```
  begin
    Format.open_box 5;
    Format.print_string ("Id { name=" ^ name ^ "; position=<something> }");
    Format.close_box;
  end
```

and here's what happens:

```
(ocd) run
run
Loading program... done.
Time: 174354
Program end.
Uncaught exception:
Failure
 "Parser internal error at line 61, column 50: ste_of_name did not find 'i'."

(ocd) load_printer _build/default/printtest.cma
load_printer _build/default/printtest.cma
File ./_build/default/printtest.cma loaded
(ocd) install_printer print_id
install_printer print_id
Unbound identifier print_id
(ocd)
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue is that your `printtest.ml` file does not really define a printer.
A printer is a function that takes a formatter and prints on this formatter.

For instance,

```ml
(* file id.ml *)
type id = Id of {name:string; position:unit }
let print_id ppf (Id {name; position=()}) =
   Format.fprintf ppf "@[Id {name=%s; position=<something>}@]" name
```

then once you have loaded the file "id.cmo" with

```
(ocd) load_printer id.cmo
```

you still have to use the qualified name for the printer:

```
(ocd) install_printer Id.print_id
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. That doesn't seem to fix the problem, though. I created id.ml with your code (after fixing the second argument to "(Id { name; position = _ })"), and get the same result: Unbound identifier Id.print_id

Comment: Did you load the cmo or cma that contains your printer?

Comment: I loaded the cma. (I don't know how to get Dune to produce a cmo.)

Comment: If you are using a dune produced library,  you are probably creating a wrapped library with a top module called `<Libname>`, then the name of the printer is probably `<Libname>.Id.print_id`.

Comment: I'm pretty clueless about libraries, and almost completely clueless when it comes to how dune deals with them, but the only .cma files in my directory are those I think the dune file explicitly says to create.

Is there a way I can tell if I'm creating a wrapped library? Where does <Libname> come from (so I can tell what it would be)?

Comment: <Libname> is the name of your library as defined in the `(name <libname>)` stanza in your dune file. Wrapped libraries are the default and must be disabled explicitly, so we are probably defining a wrapped library.

Comment: After your first reply, I created a new file called 'id.ml' that had your code (with the typo fixed) and nothing more. The resulting library is 'Id.cma'. I've tried 'install_printer print_id' and 'install_printer Id.print_id' and (for good measure) 'install_printer Id.Id.print_id' all with the same result: Unbound identifier.